# SQL Server n Times Fixed Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, rows, common-table-expression

So, business people have asked me to display the data in a particular way.
They need to display X amount of columns for a particular value and if the value is not there, then fill it with zero.

In other words, what I have:
[image]

And what I need:

[image]

I dont know if I should approach this with a pivot or a CTE and a loop... can you help me?

Using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and conditional aggregation to do this pivoting

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT RECORD_ID,
                NUMBER,
                Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY RECORD_ID ORDER BY NUMBER ) AS RN
         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT RECORD_ID,
       COALESCE(Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN NUMBER END),0) AS NUMBER01,
       COALESCE(Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN NUMBER END),0) AS NUMBER02,
       COALESCE(Max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN NUMBER END),0) AS NUMBER03,
       COALESCE(Max(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN NUMBER END),0) AS NUMBER04,
       COALESCE(Max(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN NUMBER END),0) AS NUMBER05,
       ...
       COALESCE(Max(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN NUMBER END),0) AS NUMBER10
FROM   CTE
GROUP  BY RECORD_ID
```

Dynamic approach

```
DECLARE @x        INT = 10, -- Replace it with required of columns 
        @intr     INT = 1,
        @col_list VARCHAR(8000)='',
        @sql      VARCHAR(max)=''

SET @sql = '    WITH cte
         AS (SELECT RECORD_ID,
                    NUMBER,
                    Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY RECORD_ID ORDER BY NUMBER ) AS RN
             FROM   yourtable)
    SELECT RECORD_ID, '


/*nothing to worry about the below while loop it is just to frame the string*/
WHILE @intr <= @x
  BEGIN
      SET @col_list += 'COALESCE(Max(CASE WHEN rn = ' + Cast(@intr AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' THEN NUMBER END),0) AS NUMBER' + Cast(@intr AS VARCHAR(50)) + ','
      SET @intr += 1
  END

SET @col_list = LEFT(@col_list, Len(@col_list) - 1)
SET @sql += @col_list + ' FROM   CTE
    GROUP  BY RECORD_ID '

EXEC ( @sql )
```